# How to choose the best column to apply IS NULL? Leetcode Database 1350

Tags: mysql

Departments Table:
information about the id of each department of a university.

| Column Name | Type |
| --- | --- |
| id (PK) | int |
| name | varchar |

Students Table:
information about the id of each student at a university and the id of the department he/she studies at.

| Column Name | Type |
| --- | --- |
| id(PK) | int |
| name | varchar |
| department_id | int |

I need to find the id and the name of all students who are enrolled in departments that no longer exists.
I wrote queries in two ways, first is

```
SELECT s.id, s.name
FROM Students s LEFT JOIN Departments d
ON s.department_id = d.id
WHERE d.id IS NULL;
```

the second query, I changed `d.id IS NULL` to `d.name IS NULL`, the runtime increases a lot. I wonder why does this happen？

Comment: I am not in favour of displaying table definitions in this way since it doesn't show indexes or FKs

Comment: _Couple of points_ Assuming the `id` field is an AutoIncrement (as it should be) then 1) it will never be NULL and 2) it will probably be indexed. Based on you having to ask this question your `name` column however will probably not be indexed,

Comment: Precede your two queries with `EXPLAIN ` to see what indices are being used in each case. Any well-defined table will have a primary key, which is indexed, and it appears that for table `Departments` that column `id` is it -- as the name would *strongly* suggest. And why else would you be joining on this column?